# Shortest Path and Dijkstra Algorithm

Tags: java, graph, dijkstra

I cannot seem to find any indication to this question on the internet and as I am in exams I am running out of time, the question is pretty simple and any explanation would be welcoming(although a simple yes or no will do as well).

For Dijkstra's algorithm, must a graph be strongly connected? That is every vertice can be reached from any other vertice? Or is it possible to have vertices that are unreachable and thus you must start at another node using the algorithm?

To add to this question: Does Dijkstra's algorithm only apply to undirected graphs? as all the examples in my textbook relate to undirected edges.

Comment: "I am in exams I am running out of time"... isn't that cheating?

Comment: @RobMurray Maybe he means he's in exam week, not an actual exam right now?

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithmc apply  on DIRECTED graphs

Comment: @technokrat Maybe, but I don't want him to be disqualified for getting direct help with a problem in an exam which allows you to access documentation on the internet.

Comment: either weighted or unweighted but with no negative edges

Comment: Sorry I am in exam week lol not in an exam. So it can be all that I have indicated? Strongly connected or weakly connected as well as undirected or directed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An undirected graph is basically just a directed graph, but with bidirectional connections. So no, Dijkstra's *can* also be applied to directed graphs.

For weakly connected graphs, it depends.

Say you have graph section A and graph section B. You can go from A into B, but not from B into A. If you start at A and want to find a shortest path into B, Dijkstra's will work. But naturally, you can't start at B and try to find a path to a node at A.

Comment: Thank You. I didn't want to assume the algorithm only worked on strong connected and bidirectional graphs.

Comment: @JmanxC In the future, whenever you're confused about stuff like this, it's good practice to draw up a graph and step through how the algorithm would work on it. It takes a bit of mental effort, but generally produces results faster than searching online for your specific graph case.